# link is clickable in debug mode not in run mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, webdriverwait

Here is the code I am using to click a link in the menu

```
public static void ClickOnALink(IWebDriver driver, string linkText)
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            Console.WriteLine("Clicking on the link which has the text");
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                if (link.Text == linkText)
                {                       
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    link.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I send the menu item text. When i run in debug mode, the test passes but in run mode the menu item is not getting clicked. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

I tried putting wait message everywhere in the code so it waits for the whole page to load. I also checked the linktext in the run mode just to see if it matches with the linktext I gave

Comment: you might try ditching the implicitwait and use explicit waits instead... wait for expected condition of elementToBeClickable. (or check state of clickable for element if you don't use those... I think in C# you have to import a custom version of expected conditions or check element's state)  The links array may also have stale elements once you iterate... simple solution is a standard sleep before grabbing the element array of links.... more complicated solution is checking for stale element exceptions and re-getting the array if thrown.

Comment: I agree with @pcalkins. Stale element exceptions are common when processing a list of elements, and there is no easy fix. If you are getting an exception, please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Your method to use a Explicit wait for Element to be be displayed and enabled before clicking

```
public static void ClickOnALink(IWebDriver driver, string linkText)
{
    if (driver != null)
    {
        IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
        Console.WriteLine("Clicking on the link which has the text");
        foreach (var link in links)
        {
            if (link.Text == linkText)
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                wait.Until(condition => link.Displayed && link.Enabled);
                link.Click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting all links and then finding the one link with the correct text can trigger a StaleElementException. You can make this code more robust by changing the locator to find the link by link text and utilize explicit waits:

```
public static void ClickLinkByLinkText(IWebDriver driver, string linkText, int secondsToWait = 10)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(linkText), "Link text is required");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait));
    var link = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.LinkText(linkText)));

    wait.Until(d => link.Displayed && link.Enabled);
    link.Click();
}
```

If this still does not work, consider using an XPath expression to find a link containing the given text:

```
...
var locator = By.XPath($"//a[contains(., \"{linkText}\")]");
var link = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(locator);

wait.Until(d => link.Displayed && link.Enabled);
...
```

As a side note, if this static method exists in a static class, you can make this an extension method:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static void ClickLinkByLinkText(this IWebDriver driver, string linkText, int secondsToWait = 10)
    { //                                   ^^^^
        ...
    }
}
```

Prefixing the first parameter with `this` allows you to call the static method using an object instance:

```
IWebDriver driver = // ... create driver

driver.ClickLinkByLinkText("About Us");
```

See the [Microsoft documentation about extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for more information.

Comment: Adding the explicit wait is working like magic. Thank you for helping me out here. You can close the ticket.